# Warning: unlink(/): Permission denied

Tags: php

Boa Tarde, eu estou com tentando deletar imagens da pasta e do banco de dados pelo php, mas infelizmente ocorre este erro: Warning: unlink(/): Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\Troia FS\GaleriaAdm.php on line 81.
Eu não sei como arrumar. como eu posso solucionar este erro ?

Código php:

```
   <?php
//error_reporting(0);
  if(isset($_POST['btnEnviar'])){
    $nome = $_FILES['tArq']['name'];
    $formato = $_FILES['tArq']['type'];
    $n = $_POST['nome'];
    $botao = $_POST['botao'];
if (empty($nome)) { echo "<script>alert('Escolha o seu arquivo');</script>"; exit(); } 
if (empty($n)) { echo "<script>alert('Digite o nome da equipe.');</script>"; exit(); } 
    $formatos = array("image/jpg", "image/png", "image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/bmp", "image/pjpeg");
    $testeType = array_search($formato, $formatos);
    if(!$testeType){
      echo "Formato inválido";
    } else {
      if(file_exists("fotos/$nome")){
        $a = 1;
        while(file_exists("fotos/[$a]$nome")){
          $a++;
        }
        $nome = "[".$a."]".$nome;
      }
      if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['tArq']['tmp_name'], "fotos/".$nome)){
         $insert = "INSERT INTO mantergaleria(`nome`,`foto`) VALUES ('{$n}', '{$nome}')";
        mysql_query($insert);
        echo "<center> Operação Realizada!!! </center>";
      } else {
        echo "<center> Operação Realizada!!! </center>";
        unlink("fotos/$nome");
      }
    }
  }

if($_POST['botao'] == 'Emitir Relátorio' ){
$sql = "SELECT IdGaleria, nome, foto FROM mantergaleria";
$consulta = mysql_query($sql);
echo '<br><br><table width="400px">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><center><b>Id Galeria</td>';
echo '<td><center><b>Nome</td>';
echo '<td><center><b>Foto</td>'; 
echo '</tr>';
while($registro = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta)){
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><center>'.$registro["IdGaleria"].'</td>';
echo '<td><center>'.$registro["nome"].'</td>';
echo '<td><center>'.$registro["foto"].'</td>'; 
echo '</tr>'; 
} 
echo '</table>'; 
} 

   if($_POST['botao'] == 'Excluir' ){
 $result = "DELETE from mantergaleria where IdGaleria = '".$_POST['IdGaleria']."'"; 
  unlink($fotos.'/'.$nome); //LINHA 81
     $ver_resultado = @mysql_query($result, $db);
    if ($ver_resultado){
     echo " <center> Operação Realizada!!! </center>";
     }else{
                 echo "Nao foi possivel excluir"; exit();
        echo @mysql_error();
     }
  }

  if($_POST['botao'] == 'Alterar' ){
  $result = "UPDATE mantergaleria SET Nome = '".$_POST['Nome']."' WHERE IdGaleria='".$IdGaleria."'";
    $ver_resultado = @mysql_query($result, $db);
    if ($result){
        echo "<center> Operação Realizada!!! </center>";
     }else{
        echo "Não foi possivel alterar os dados: $Nome, $IdGaleria" ;
        echo mysql_error();
        }
 }

?>
```

Comment: Poste o código completo, assim fica mais fácil. Precisamos saber sobre a variavel $fotos e $nome

Comment: Pronto já alterei na pergunta

Comment: Isso aí é problema com permissões na pasta, onde o arquivo é excluido

Comment: A solução é dar permissão ao arquivo, mas tenho até medo de sugerir isto, porque é comum as pessoas escancararem a segurança quando vão fazer isto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é porque a variável `$nome` só irá ser válida após uma requisição `POST` do **btnEnviar**, ou seja, só será válida no bloco desse `IF`

```
if(isset($_POST['btnEnviar'])){ //linha 3
```

Para você fazer funcionar corretamente você terá que fazer uma listagem dos itens do banco de dados (aonde estão os registros das imagens) e criar um link, como por exemplo

http://localhost/excluir.php?id=ID-REGISTRO-BANCO-DE-DADOS&imagem=IMAGEM.jpg

Após fazer isso, você cria uma verificação `GET` mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["id"])) AND isset($_GET["imagem"])){

$result = "DELETE from mantergaleria where IdGaleria = '".$_GET['id']."'";

  unlink('fotos/'.$_GET['imagem']); //LINHA 81
     $ver_resultado = @mysql_query($result, $db);
    if ($ver_resultado){
     echo " <center> Operação Realizada!!! </center>";
     }else{
                 echo "Nao foi possivel excluir"; exit();
        echo @mysql_error();
     }

}
?>
```

Desse jeito ele irá excluir o registro do banco de dados referente a **id** e também excluir a imagem com o nome que está em **imagem**, fazendo um link como por exemplo

http://localhost.php?id=10&imagem=galeria1.jpg

Então ele irá excluir o registro com a ID **10** e a imagem com o nome **galeria1.jpg**

Você pode lapidar seu código para verificar se a imagem existe no diretório, se o registro com a ID passada também existe no banco de dados, etc. Isso ai você que decide.